# How can I add in current menu fontawesome <i>

Tags: php, html

I am trying to indicate the active menu using an icon in PHP.

Here my html version :

```
<ul class="languages">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="page_home1.html#">English <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="page_home1.html#">Spanish</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here my PHP version

```
<li class="languagesSelector">
    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    <a><?php echo __("Languages") ?></a>
    <ul class="languages">
        <?php
        $currentLanguage = $user->language; // remember language
        foreach($languages as $language) {
            if(!$page->viewable($language)) continue; // is page viewable in this language?
            $user->language = $language;
            if($language->id == $currentLanguage->id) {
                echo "<li class='active'>" <i class='fa fa-check'></i> ;
            } else {
                echo "<li>";
            }
            echo "<a href='$page->url'>$language->title</a></li>";
        }
        $user->language = $currentLanguage; // restore language
        ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How can I achieve do this using just a function in PHP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed your code snippets so they line up correctly (improving the readability) and I also reworded your question to it was easy to pick out.

Comment: What's happening? More importantly, what's *not* happening? Give us some **specifics** so we can give you a more exact solution.

Comment: Probably just a typo, but your echo line must be: `echo "<li class='active'><i class="fa fa-check"></i>";`. Also, I don't get why you need a function to add the icons, if you could explain more...